# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'checkIfIsOnDomain' was called

Tags: angular

I keep getting the error whenever I run ng build on Angular 8:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'HomeModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'checkIfIsOnDomain' was called.
```

How can I fix it? I need to load a different set of routes depending on whether the user is on a subdomain or not. The code works fine on ng serve.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(RouterService.checkIfIsOnDomain() ? routes : RouterService.getSubdomainRoutes('../..')),
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
```

Code in RouterService:

```
static checkIfIsOnDomain() {
    const full = window.location.host;
    const parts = full.split('.');
    let result = true;
    if (parts[0] && parts[1] && parts[2]) {
      result = false;
      (window as any).Intercom('update', {
        'hide_default_launcher': true
      });
    }
    return result;
  }

  static getSubdomainRoutes(path) {
    return [
      { path: '', loadChildren: `${path}/website/website.module#WebsiteModule` }
    ];
  }
```

Comment: As error says, method calls are not supported in decorators (`@NgModel` is one of them). What you want to achieve? Maybe there is other sollution.

Comment: I need to load a different set of routes depending on whether the user is on a subdomain or not. The method checkIfIsOnDomain() handles this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load all routes and with `CanActivate` decide if user can (or should be able) to visit your "site" if he is on domain or subdomain. If you want to optimize it, you can create several of modules ans import them lazily.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Compiler complies routes statically. Angular compiler doesn't run your code. Angualr compiler runs in nodejs context; therefore, it doesn't know what is `window.location.host` because it's not a browser. Angular compiler only looks at the routes definitions and it makes decisions on how to bundle your code. For example, if you define lazy loaded modules it will split the module in a different file.

You cannot use a function to generate routes definitions. I would suggest two ways to tackle this.

You can convert your application to a workspace (I am assuming you are using Angular CLI). Here you can have two application: one for domain.com and the other for sub.domain.com. Any shared component you can have them in a lib project. You can read more: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config

The other way is to use dynamic module loading. You create a module for each domain.com and sub.domain.com. Each module will define routes statically. After that, using dynamic loading, you can write a code to choose which module to load based on the current route. Dynamic module loading is an advanced topic. You can learn more about it here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28

Comment: I need to load a different set of routes depending on whether the user visits my website at example.domain.com or domain.com.

Comment: I modified the answer. please check